# 404 not found for laravel api Url's

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api

I have api call from react to laravel as backend

```
 const response=await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/getcandidates/");
```

but I got response as Kanban.jsx:65

> GET http://localhost:8000/api/getcandidates/ 404 (Not Found)

and here is my api.php

```
Route::get('/getcandidates',[EmployeeController::class,'index']);

Route::get('/getcandidates_schedule',[EmployeeController::class,'scheduleresponse']);
Route::get('/getcandidates_rejection',[EmployeeController::class,'rejectionreponse']);
Route::get('/getcandidates_waiting',[EmployeeController::class,'waitingresponse']);
Route::post('/add_employee_first',[EmployeeController::class,'store']);
Route::post('/updatecolumn',[EmployeeController::class,'updatecolumn']);

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

output of `php artisan route:list:`

```
 Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api        |
|        |          |          |      |         | auth:api   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------
```

Please help me .

Comment: try without the forward slash at the end `const response=await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/getcandidates");`

Comment: @zahidhasanemon thanks for the reply.. but it's not working

Comment: There are only two routes in the list. Run `php artisan optimize:clear`, and then `php artisan route:list` again.